# How to automatically select the dropdown which is pulling from the database by using id as an input

Tags: java, function, jsp, struts

I am trying for a week that, Scenario: The table Alphabet having 3 values with two columns ID  Alphabet
1      A
2      B
3      C

This values are pulling by java code which shows in JSP as Dropdown.
If user typed 2 in another textbox and submit. Automatically the Alphabet dropdown will select B and visible in dropdown. It should match the user typed value with the Dropdown ID and It should select B automatically in the dropdown.

JSP

```
  <html:text property="usergivenID" name="alphaForm"/> <td>
  <html:select property="alphaId" name="alphaForm" onchange="automate();">
 <html:option value=''><bean:message key="default.dropDownValue"/></html:option>
<html:options collection="alpList" name="form" property="label" labelProperty="value" />
 </html:select></td>
    
        function automate(){
            var options = document.forms[0].usergivenID.value;
            var opt=document.forms[0].alphatId.option;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
              if (options[i].text == document.forms[0].alphaId.option) {
                  opt[i].selcted=true;
                break;}
              }
            }
```

Eg: If user gives  3 in usergivenID it should compare whit the alphabetID and should select B automatically.The above code I tried but ist not working